# Prove $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}=a $ , if $a_n>0 \thinspace (n = 1,2,3, \cdots)$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=a$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

**Prove  $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}=a  $ , if $a_n>0 \thinspace (n = 1,2,3, \cdots)$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=a$**

I am learning Real Analysis and this is a home work. I made a solution for it but the equation 2 and equation 4 in my solution  can not convince myself.

I am not sure whether can I just take the limit of the exponent instead of the power?

I learned that the limits can add or subtract or multiply or divide, but I don't know about the exponent.

Can you tell me which theorem did I miss in that point?

Below is the proof I made. Hope you can point out my weakness or explain me another way to solve it because my proof is too verbose. Thank you!

**Proof**

Because
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=a$$
So we have
$$ \forall \epsilon>0, \exists N, \forall n > N: |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-a|<\epsilon$$
so
$$a-\epsilon<\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<a+\epsilon$$
so for the $N+1, N+2,\cdots,n-1$ term, we have $n-N-1$ inequities:
$$a-\epsilon<\frac{a_{N+2}}{a_{N+1}}<a+\epsilon,\quad a-\epsilon<\frac{a_{N+3}}{a_{N+2}}<a+\epsilon\quad ,\cdots,\quad a-\epsilon<\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n-1}}<a+\epsilon$$

(we will keep $\epsilon$ very small so that $a-\epsilon>0$)

then we time them together to get:
$$(a-\epsilon)^{n-N-1}<\frac{a_n}{a_{N+1}}<(a+\epsilon)^{n-N-1}$$
then we multiply $a_{N+1}$ in every side of the inequity , we get:
$$a_{N+1}(a-\epsilon)^{n-N-1}<{a_n}<a_{N+1}(a+\epsilon)^{n-N-1}$$
then we take the $n^\text{th}$root:(below is inequality 1)
\begin{equation}\label{general}
 \sqrt[n]{a_{N+1}}(a-\epsilon)^{1-\frac{N+1}{n}}<\sqrt[n]{a_n}<\sqrt[n]{a_{N+1}}(a+\epsilon)^{1-\frac{N+1}{n}}
\end{equation}

because (below is equation 2, **I AM NOT SURE HERE**)
\begin{equation}
 \lim_{n \to \infty}[\sqrt[n]{a_{N+1}}(a-\epsilon)^{1-\frac{N+1}{n}}] =\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{a_{N+1}}\cdot \lim_{n \to \infty}(a-\epsilon)^{1-\frac{N+1}{n}} = 1 \cdot (a-\epsilon)=a-\epsilon
\end{equation}

so for $\forall \epsilon_2 > 0 , \exists N_2 , \forall n>N_2:$
$$|\sqrt[n]{a_{N+1}}(a-\epsilon)^{1-\frac{N+1}{n}}-(a-\epsilon)|<\epsilon_2$$
it is
$$a-\epsilon-\epsilon_2<\sqrt[n]{a_{N+1}}(a-\epsilon)^{1-\frac{N+1}{n}}<a-\epsilon +\epsilon_2$$
we take the left side:(below is inequity 3)
\begin{equation}\label{result1}
 a-\epsilon-\epsilon_2<\sqrt[n]{a_{N+1}}(a-\epsilon)^{1-\frac{N+1}{n}}
\end{equation}

because (below is equation 4)
\begin{equation}
 \lim_{n \to \infty}[\sqrt[n]{a_{N+1}}(a+\epsilon)^{1-\frac{N+1}{n}}] =a+\epsilon
\end{equation}
so for the same $\epsilon_2 > 0 , \exists N_3 , \forall n>N_3:$
$$|\sqrt[n]{a_{N+1}}(a+\epsilon)^{1-\frac{N+1}{n}}-(a+\epsilon)|<\epsilon_2$$
it is
$$a+\epsilon-\epsilon_2<\sqrt[n]{a_{N+1}}(a+\epsilon)^{1-\frac{N+1}{n}}<a+\epsilon +\epsilon_2$$
we take the right side:(below is inequity 5)
\begin{equation}\label{result2}
 \sqrt[n]{a_{N+1}}(a+\epsilon)^{1-\frac{N+1}{n}}<a+\epsilon +\epsilon_2
\end{equation}
bring inequity (3)  (5) back to inequity (1), we have:

$$\forall \epsilon, \epsilon_2>0 ,  \exists N_4=max\{N, N_2, N_3\}, \forall n > N_4 : $$
$$a-\epsilon-\epsilon_2<\sqrt[n]{a_n}<a+\epsilon+\epsilon_2$$
It is the same as : $$\forall \epsilon >0 , \exists N , \forall n>N : |\sqrt[n]{a_n}-a|<\epsilon$$

So the statement  has been proved.

Answer (score 1):

After equations $2$ and $4$, you can go straight to:

$$a-\epsilon<\sqrt[n]{a_n}<a+\epsilon$$

by taking the limits of inequality $1$, without needing all the extra stuff you have written.